# What are likely SSIS interview questions for a beginner?

Tags: ssis

For a beginner having an experience of 6 months in SSIS what are the most probable questions?

For Control tabs, Each section of dataflow tabs like what are the most used Transformations in day to day life (I know that all are important as it depends on the project requirements) etc?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [SSIS interview questions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/b2ede456-ce40-4978-ba86-0b42270da875/)

also

- [SSIS Interview Questions](http://sqlserversolutions.blogspot.com/2009/02/ssis-interview-questions.html)
- [SSIS Interview Questions](http://www.scribd.com/doc/15421263/SSIS-Interview-Questions)
- [Sql Server Integration services
  Interview questions](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/158771-Sql-Server-Integration-services-Interview-questions.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As we get into an age where business/functional knowledge is given importance, one of the first questions you should be prepared to answer very well is: "What was the project about?" Beginner may end up answering "Well we had to transform Data." But this won't do. You would be expected to talk about the business purposed behind needing to transform data...Hence, industry knowledge helps.